# Uploading Files Using php | Files are not being uploaded anymore

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, uploading

I am uploading files to my database using PHP. Everything was working in the beginning, but it suddenly stopped working. 
here is my code

```
print "<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
print "<td class='tesname'>". $row['exam_name']. "</td>";
print "<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='".$_GET['user_id']."'>";
print "<input type='hidden' name='lab_name' value='".$row['exam_name']."'>";                        
print "<td class='tesdate'><input class='form-control' type='Date' autofocus  id='TestDate' placeholder='Test Date' name='testDate'></td>";
print "<td><input type='file' class='file-input' id='myfile' placeholder='Upload' name='myfile'></td>";
print "<td><input type='hidden' name='exam_id' value='".$row['exam_id']."'>
<button type='Submit' class='btn btn-info' name='btn'>upload</button></td>
</form>
```

and here is the PHP code

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ehr_new","root", "");

if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
    $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into patinet_examination values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$_POST['testDate']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$_POST['exam_id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$_POST['user_id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$_POST['lab_name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(5,$name);
    $stmt->bindParam(6,$type);
    $stmt->bindParam(7,$data);
    $stmt->execute();
    print "success";
}
```

as i said everything was working fine, and suddenly the query is refusing to insert to the database.

also, here is my db structure

[image: db structure]

Thank you

Comment: Can you output the error you are receiving and also the DB structure.

Comment: Ok, but what happens? What error messages do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. that's the confusing thing. I am going to upload a picture of the database structure.

Comment: put a try catch block around the code, maybe you are getting exception.

Comment: @Marco sorry, I have never used exception handling in php :( *embarrassing moment*

Comment: _Side note:_ Don't print large chunks of HTML using PHP. Just close the PHP block `?>`, write your HTML and open a new PHP block: `<?php`. That will make your code easier to read and IDE's will also be able to syntax highlight the HTML as well.

Comment: Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` just after the connection

Comment: Don't worry bro, it's very easy and simple. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Have you suddenly started uploading very large files? I notice you never look at `$_FILES['myfile']['error']` to check the file uploaded

Comment: I see `exam_id` is unique, probably you already have the same `exam_id` already existing.

Comment: I got this error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '21' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ehr\lab-result.php:145 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ehr\lab-result.php(145): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ehr\lab-result.php on line 145

Comment: exam_id is a unique key, and you are adding a duplicate ID. It should not be a primary key if you can have two rows with the same exam_id.

Comment: And now you've learned the magic of handling exceptions :)  You should always use it.

Comment: thank you so much, guys. it is working now it was the primary key. love you all :D <3